# Printing excel workbook without white space between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working to provide an extensive xls-based form, which is then to be filled by various users and submitted to a committee deciding about the files.

The form will need to be printed for this last step, and as some sheets are limited to a couple lines only and others could flow over to a 2nd or 3rd page depending on free text user input, I see the risk of having a lot of white space in the printouts (e.g. three quarters empty pages).

I have considered/am considering some ideas to get this done:

Moving all individual sheets to one sheet, which is then printed more conveniently - probably not a good idea because of the variety of needed column widths making it impossible to properly format anything

Possibly coding in VBA to copy the individual sheets (by print areas) to a word doc, which is then printed easily - I know basic VBA, but would definitely need guidance as to how this could be achieved

Does anyone on here have other ideas or guidance on the ones posed above?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is a pitty that your first question here is not really a good fit for SO, as it is very subjective, and potentially attracts opinionated answers. I can only suggest a third option, actually a variation on your second one. You can use linking / embedding instead of VBA to include selected parts from your Excel workbooks in a word document. As a work process I believe it is easier and more efficient than writing a one time VBA code for the same task.

Comment: Btw, please, take [**The Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a brief intro on Stack Overflow, and then read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what you can ask about and how to present your question.

Comment: hi Tom, many thanks for your response. Maybe I did not make it very clear in my initial post, but the sheet is for multi use in an organization, so it would not be an effort for a one time result